# how can you make an API change its data?

Tags: javascript, python, django

This is the code I have, when it is clicked it should detect the URL inputted in a form, and then it runs a scraper that prints out the emails found on the URL. I want the results to be printed on the same page. How should I make my API to achieve this?

Javascript code:

```
function submitURL() {

 const url = document.querySelector("#InputSearch").value;
 const data = { url };

 fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(data),
 })
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => {
   console.log('Success:', data);
 })
 .catch((error) => {
   console.error('Error:', error);
 });
}
```

Current API created (I want this to take the data of the emails found):

```
class apiOverview(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.EmailsSerializer


    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            url = serializer.validated_data.get('url')
            message = f'The url is {url}'
            return Response({'message': message})
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def patch(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'method': 'PATCH'})

    def put(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'method': 'PUT'})

    def delete(self, request, pk=None):
        return Response({'method': 'DELETE'})
```

Comment: For data to change in the api itself, i don't think that would be a good idea as users would share that changed data. Unless you authenticated users by assigning them each an id that could be a viable way of updating the api object. I am not sure what you mean by same page. DO you mean print the response from the server in javascript? It looks like you are already doing that...?

Comment: if you plan on storing your data in the api

Comment: yes, I guess to print the response from the server to Javascript. I see that it is already doing that. But no informaton pops out...

Comment: there might be something wrong with logging in your browser. Check for errors and if there aren't any, try alerting the value instead unless you have already tried.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the results from the API call in your document with javascript, with data from response as `data`:

```
let dataArea = document.createElement('p');
data['dataPoints'].forEach(dataPoint =>
      let dataChunk = document.createElement('p');
      dataChunk.innerText = dataPoint.text;
      dataArea.appendChild(dataChunk);
)
```

If you would prefer to use jQuery, there are more options over there:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` I dont know why it says this error